# Android AlertDialog Title Font has different sizes

Tags: android, fonts, dialog, styles, themes

I'm having a weird "problem".

I have a static function that creates an AlertDialog box. I pass the current Context as a parameter. It's a pretty basic AlertDialog.Builder, not a lot of code.

But calling the function from two different Activities gives different results:

[image: Different dialog fonts]

The difference seems to be that the "Title" font is Larger in "A", while in "B" it's the same size. But the exact same code creates both Dialogs (suggesting that it's something inherited from the parent Activity.) Where should I start looking?

Comment: Of course, the "problem" seems to have gone away now, and I don't believe I changed anything. Perhaps this was a bug in Eclipse or the Emulator... I will keep an eye on it.